# How to disable push on view when editing TableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I'm trying to realise multi selection edit in my UITableView.
On selection trigger of UICell i'm pushing on another view.
And if i set

```
[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

and try to check cell it pushs.

Can I disable push when editing table?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (!tableView.editing) {
        // code for normal state (push)
    } else {
        // code for editing state
    }
}
```

This should do.